# I want to sort some parameters but gives me [object object] or not undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

```
"text": "Introducing the Twitter Certified Products Program:
"retweet_count": 121, 
"in_reply_to_status_id_str": null, 
"id": 240859602684612608, 
"geo": null, 
"retweeted": false, 
"possibly_sensitive": false, 
"in_reply_to_user_id": null, 
"place": null, 
"user": { 
"profile_sidebar_fill_color": "DDEEF6", 
"profile_sidebar_border_color": "C0DEED", 
"profile_background_tile": false, 
"name": "Twitter API", 
"profile_image_url": "http://a0.twimg.com/profile_images/2284... 
"created_at": "Wed May 23 06:01:13 +0000 2007", 
"location": "San Francisco, CA", 
"follow_request_sent": false, 
"profile_link_color": "0084B4", 
"is_translator": false, 
"id_str": "6253282", 
"entities": {
        "url": {
          "urls": [
            {
              "expanded_url": null,
              "url": "",
              "indices": [
                0,
                22
              ]
            }
          ]
        },
        "description": {
          "urls": [

          ]
        }
      },
```

**jquery**

```
success: function(data) { 
var result = JSON.parse(data);  $.each(result, function (i, val) {  
document.write(val.text+" "+val.retweet_count+" 
"); 
});
```

Comment: Make sure `data` is a string containing array. `console.log` it and log `typeof` of it.

Comment: This is what brings me  {\"created_at\":\"Sun Mar 19 22:40:16 +00002017\",\"entities\":{\"hashtags\":[{\"text\":\"GraciasBravoPueblo\",\"indices\":[25,44]}],\"symbols\":[],\"user_mentions\":[],\"urls\"{\"url\":\"https:\\\/\\\/t.co\\\/Q3xYg8k0vG\",\"expanded_url\":\"https:\\\/\\\/www.periscope.tv\\\/w\\\/a52u0DMwODk2N3wxbFBKcVpucGt6UHhiRDU_d9NnWueV1e9n7I7dzqVY2dNH8EG7gJlSLWlsWDA=\",\"display_url\":\"periscope.tv\\\/w\\\/a52u0DMwODk2\\u2026\",\"indices\":[45,68]}]}},                                  and I want to access \ "entities \": {\ "hashtags \": [{\ "text \": \ "Thanks \", using $ .each

Comment: Make sure you call `$.each` on an array, not an object. E.g.: `var result = JSON.parse('{"hashtags":[{"text":"FOOBAR"}]}'); result.hashtags.forEach( function(val) { console.log(val); } )`

Comment: $.ajax({
  url: 'data.php',
   type: "get",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data) {
       
 var results = JSON.parse(data); 
   $.each(results, function (i, val) {
     console.log(val.entities.hashtags[0]); 
    } );                                                                                                               result console  :                                                                                                               Object
indices:
Array[2]
text:"DiaInternacionalDeLaFelicidad"
__proto__
:
Objects 
How do I display the text?

Comment: Please include the full relevant part of the JSON text, malformed JSON isn't helpful in answering a question. Also include the full `$.ajax` call in your question, only seeing the `success` could hide what is the actual issue here. Please also include the full error message in the body of the question and what line you are receiving it on. Read [mcve], following it's advice will help you get a useful answer.

Answer (score 0):

"text": "Introducing the Twitter Certified Products Program: 
It should be:

"text": "Introducing the Twitter Certified Products Program:",

You are missing a " and a comma.

Comment: This is not the problem is just reference, the problem is when I try to show the parameters, for example the parameter "text" shows me perfect but when I try to access the "user" parameter it returns me [object object] and when I try to show The parameter "name" that this in turn is inside the parameter "user" as shown in the code returns me undefined that is my question @patriciaBesho

Comment: @EzequielGuerra User is an object, so you need to parse that too. That's why it returns [object object].